# commutation relations for operators in projected subspaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, linear-algebra, majorana-fermions

I am looking for a consistent re-definition of commutators for certain operators when I work in a projected subspace. Basically, I have a spin defined in terms of 4 Majorana operators $b_{x}$, $b_{y}$, $b_{z}$, $c$ with projected subspace defined by  $b_{x}b_{y}b_{z}c\equiv 1$ by which I mean, we work in the subspace where the operator $b_{x}b_{y}b_{z}c$ has eigenvalue +1 . I see that if I consider this as an operator relation, I am no longer able to make the usual Majorana commutation relations hold. Basically, is there any way I can use the projection as an operator equation and have a consistent definition of objects, Majorana fermions as I began with them ?

Comment: What commutation relations of Majorana fermions fail to hold?

Comment: Like if I write $b_{x}=cb_{z}b_{y}$, then $b_{x}^2$ is no longer equal to 1, or that $b_{x}$ no longer commutes with $b_{x}$

Comment: The logic is that we can use the Majorana operators in the unrestricted Hilbert space before projection, and only after projection you have spin operators $\sigma^a=ib^ac$, at which point there are no longer any Majorana modes.